# php save data into two rows at a time in database?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a form like this

```
<form class="product-data" action="">
    <table>
        <tr class="data-row">
            <td> 
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][source_unit]" >
            </td>
            <td >
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][target_unit]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][client_price]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][client_salary]" >
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][source_unit]" >
        </td>
        <td >
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][target_unit]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][client_price]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][client_salary]" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

here you can see I have two rows. One for a and another for b. Now I want to save them in the database with two rows. One for the a and another for b at a same time. When I am doing print_r(finance). with this code

```
$finances = $_POST['finance'];
    print_r($finances);
```

Its showing me an array like this

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [source_unit] => 3213
            [target_unit] => 657654322343
            [client_price] => 5435.00
            [client_salary] => 897.00
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [source_units] => 67656565
            [target_units] => 43243
            [client_price] => 23432.00
            [client_salary] => 6546.00
        )

)
```

Now can someone tell me how to save them in each row. I have my database table is like this and the data should be saved like this

```
Id, product_type, source_unit, target_unit, client_price, lient_salary
1       A            3213        657654322343     5435           897
2       B            67656565     43243           23432           6546
```

Comment: Whats the result of `var_dump(count($finances));`? Im just wondering

Comment: @Loko its like this `array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["source_unit"]=>
    string(4) "3213"
    ["target_unit"]=>
    string(12) "657654322343"
    ["client_price"]=>
    string(7) "5435.00"
    ["client_salary"]=>
    string(6) "897.00"
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["source_units"]=>
    string(8) "67656565"
    ["target_units"]=>
    string(5) "43243"
    ["client_price"]=>
    string(8) "23432.00"
    ["client_salary"]=>
    string(7) "6546.00"
  }
}`

Comment: also why are both array's `[A]`? Shouldn't the second array be `[B]`?

Comment: That's not the result of just `var_dump(count($finances));` Can you try to find just the result of `var_dump(count($finances));` ?

Comment: Ok thanks let me check something real quick.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you or do you still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you. Once that is tailored for this scenario only:

```
$f = $_POST['finance'];

// insert first row
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (NULL, 'A', {$f['a']['source_unit']}, {$f['a']['target_units']}, {$f['a']['client_price']}, {$f['a']['client_salary']})";
mysql_query($query);

// insert second row
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (NULL, 'B', {$f['b']['source_unit']}, {$f['b']['target_units']}, {$f['b']['client_price']}, {$f['b']['client_salary']})";
mysql_query($query);
```

or if you have it more universal (for multiple rows):

```
$f = $_POST['finance'];

foreach($f as $key => $item) {
    // assign key of the letter as value to insert
    $letter = strtoupper($key);

    // insert a row
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (NULL, '{$letter}', {$item['source_unit']}, {$item['target_units']}, {$item['client_price']}, {$item['client_salary']})";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Dont use `mysql`... This is a bad answer just because of the `mysql` part.

Answer (score 0):

loop thru your array and either insert or update accordingly.

```
    foreach($finances as $key => $data)
    {
    //based on the $key if value exists in database update else insert
    echo $key.'<br />';
    echo $data['source_unit'].'<br />';
    echo $data['target_unit'].'<br />';
    echo '<hr />';
    }
```