# Adding two rows in MySQL table together

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I don't have much experience with MySQL so please bear with me :)

I have created a table of fast food items with their calories and carbohydrates - two rows seen below:

```
Food Name________Calories________Total_Carbs

Big Mac_____________508_______________43 

Quarter Pounder______518_______________37
```

I was wondering if it is possible for me to allow a user to type in the name of two food items into a text box and when they press submit it would add the two values of the carbohydrates together and output the answer?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to run the INSERT statement for each added food item.

Comment: @Youssef `INSERT`? I don't think so..

Comment: two input row sets in one textbox? why would you want that?

Comment: @ElonThan you're right i completely misunderstood the question

Comment: check this question answer.
i hope it will help u.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498185/php-save-data-into-two-rows-at-a-time-in-database

Answer (score -1):

you'll need to sepcify some sort of separator in your textbox, then in your PHP handler you just need to execute a query that sums Carbs for the specified food items.
Example:

```
//considering your separator is a ','
//also need to make sure the user enters exactly 2 food names, otherwise use implode to build the WHERE part of the query
$food_items = explode(',', $_POST['food']);
$q = "SELECT SUM(Total_Carbs) AS carbs FROM myTable WHERE Food_name= $food_items[0] OR Food_name=$food_items[1]";
//execute ...
```

Of course you'll need to adapt this to your exact variable names...